# Copy a list from one SharePoint site to another using web services (no Object Model)

Tags: 2007, web-services, windows-application

How can I copy a list (including fields, views or Schema) from one SharePoint web site and create an equivalent list instance on another SharePoint web site (which can be in a different site collection) using OOB MOSS web services.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the "Save List as Template" functionality available in the List Settings.

Comment: My requirement is to create an .net application which can accomplish this task.

Comment: This answers the question, the way it is currently phrased. +1

Answer (score 0):

Check out my SPServices jQuery library for help on this. http://spservices.codeplex.com

It'll be a combination of GetList and AddList.

Comment: Can I use this library in a Windows Application?

Comment: I can't see why not, but it all depends on what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using any interface that supports SOAP calls.  I use [MSXML2.XMLHTTP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms759148%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) regularly.  You will need to use [GetList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.getlist%28v=office.12%29.aspx) to retrieve information about the source list, and [AddList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.addlist%28v=office.12%29.aspx) to create the destination list.  Similarly, you can [GetView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/views.views.getview%28v=office.12%29.aspx) and [AddView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/views.views.addview%28v=office.12%29.aspx) to copy the views.